# My custom sidebar didn't fill the entire column in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, ejs

My sidebar didnt fill entire `column` from bootstrap. i didnt define the `width` for the sidebar

here is my css for sidebar

```
       .sidebar {
            position: fixed;
            /* top: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
            width:100%; 
            z-index: 100; */ /* Behind the navbar */
            background-color: #3A3735;
        }
    
    .sidebar-sticky {
        position: relative;
        top: 0;
        height: 100vh;
        padding-top: .5rem;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        overflow-y: auto; /* Scrollable contents if viewport is shorter than content. */
    }
    
    @supports ((position: -webkit-sticky) or (position: sticky)) {
    .sidebar-sticky {
        position: -webkit-sticky;
        position: sticky;
    }
    }
    
    .sidebar .nav-link {
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #ffffff;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    }
    
    
    .sidebar .nav-link.active {
    color: #3A3735;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    }
    
    .sidebar .nav-link:hover .icon-sidebar,
    .sidebar .nav-link.active .icon-sidebar {
    color: green;
    }
    
    .sidebar-heading {
    font-size: .75rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    }
```

my html looks like this

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-2">
      <nav id="sidebarMenu" class="sidebar">
        <div class="sidebar-sticky pt-3">
            <p class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
                <a href="#">
                <img src="img/logo-white.svg" alt="home">
                </a>
            </p>
            <ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column mx-4">
                <li class="nav-item mb-2">
                    <a class="nav-link active" href="#">
                    <img src="img/sidebar/home.svg" class="mr-3 icon-sidebar" alt="">
                    Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item mb-2">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                    <img src="img/sidebar/check-circle.svg" class="mr-3 icon-sidebar" alt="">
                    Goal
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item mb-2">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                    <img src="img/sidebar/clipboard.svg" class="mr-3 icon-sidebar" alt="">
                    To Do
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item mb-2">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                    <img src="img/sidebar/calendar.svg" class="mr-3 icon-sidebar" alt="">
                    Kalender
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul> 
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>

    <div class="col-10">
    </div>
</div>
```

currently im using bootstrap 4.6 version.
and here is my full code in github:

for css
https://github.com/gergerchan/testingfrontend/blob/feature/goal-dan-register/assets/css/sidebar.css

for the sidebar
https://github.com/gergerchan/testingfrontend/blob/feature/goal-dan-register/views/partials/sidebar.ejs

for the full html
https://github.com/gergerchan/testingfrontend/blob/feature/goal-dan-register/views/goal.ejs

update :
i remove `position:fixed` and change it to `height :100%`
but when i scroll now my side bar content will scroll too.

i am using nodejs, express js, and for the view engine i use ejs.

thank you before

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check the below code? Hope it will work for you. We have remove `position: fixed` form `sidebar` and add `row` element in parents of `col-*`

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <style>
    .sidebar {
      /* position: fixed; */
      /* top: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
            width:100%; 
            z-index: 100; */
      /* Behind the navbar */
      background-color: #3A3735;
    }
    
    .sidebar-sticky {
      position: relative;
      top: 0;
      height: 100vh;
      padding-top: .5rem;
      overflow-x: hidden;
      overflow-y: auto;
      /* Scrollable contents if viewport is shorter than content. */
    }
    
    @supports ((position: -webkit-sticky) or (position: sticky)) {
      .sidebar-sticky {
        position: -webkit-sticky;
        position: sticky;
      }
    }
    
    .sidebar .nav-link {
      font-weight: 500;
      color: #ffffff;
      margin-bottom: 15px;
    }
    
    .sidebar .nav-link.active {
      color: #3A3735;
      background-color: #fff;
      padding-top: 5px;
      padding-bottom: 5px;
      border-radius: 30px;
    }
    
    .sidebar .nav-link:hover .icon-sidebar,
    .sidebar .nav-link.active .icon-sidebar {
      color: green;
    }
    
    .sidebar-heading {
      font-size: .75rem;
      text-transform: uppercase;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-2">
      <nav id="sidebarMenu" class="sidebar">
        <div class="sidebar-sticky pt-3">
          <p class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
            <a href="#">
              <img src="img/logo-white.svg" alt="home">
            </a>
          </p>
          <ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column mx-4">
            <li class="nav-item mb-2">
              <a class="nav-link active" href="#">
                <img src="img/sidebar/home.svg" class="mr-3 icon-sidebar" alt=""> Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item mb-2">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                <img src="img/sidebar/check-circle.svg" class="mr-3 icon-sidebar" alt=""> Goal
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item mb-2">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                <img src="img/sidebar/clipboard.svg" class="mr-3 icon-sidebar" alt=""> To Do
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item mb-2">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                <img src="img/sidebar/calendar.svg" class="mr-3 icon-sidebar" alt=""> Kalender
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="col-10">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thank you for your response.
i already have row in my body. the problem if i remove the position fixed in the sidebar, and i scroll. my sidebar will not stay in the position